# How to find lines with multiple occurrences of a(ny) word in a file?

Tags: regex, grep, field, multiple-columns, custom-fields

I want to find lines that have multiple occurrences of a(ny) word.  For example, if the input text is

```
John is a teacher, who is not highly paid.
abc abcde
James lives in Detroit.
abc abc abcde
Paul has 2 dogs and 2 cats.
```

The output should be

```
John is a teacher, who is not highly paid.
abc abc abcde
Paul has 2 dogs and 2 cats.
```

First line has `is` repeated, second line has `abc` repeated and last line has `2` repeated.

Comment: The second line has `abc` repeated. Did you mean repeated words?

Comment: yes, but any word, not specific word.

Comment: Please fix the question. It says any string, not any word. I posted a wrong answer because of this.

Comment: I edited it for you. Yes, it's whitespace. A string is any sequence of characters, for instance `bc` inside `abcde` is a string. A word is a sequence  of letters and numbers surrounded by whitespace or puctuation.

Comment: I disagree to an extent though.  In that sense, every alphabet/character can be termed a string.  'John lives in Detroit' should also come because i,n,e,t,o,i all are repeated!

Comment: That's my point. You don't want those repetitions. That's why the question was incorrectly written.

Comment: Should `Paul` and `paul` be counted as `2` or `1` word? (Ignore case).

Comment: Paul and paul are different.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?=.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/6

Use this with `grep -P`

Comment: yes it works.  Thanks.  I am trying to understand the command though and if it works in all variants of *x!

Comment: you got my +1. what does "?=" means?

Comment: @qqibrow it mean a lookahead.It is a 0 width assertion which just checks for the condition ahead

Comment: 'grep - P' does not work in all shells.  I do get 'grep: The -P option is not supported' in some shells.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it in `awk`

```
awk '{f=0;delete a;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (a[$i]++) f=1} f' file
John is a teacher, who is not highly paid.
abc abc abcde
Paul has 2 dogs and 2 cats.
```

It loops trough every word and count them in array `a`
If any word found more than once, set flag `f`
If flag `f` is true, do default action, print line.

---

To see how many:

```
awk '{f=0;delete a;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (a[$i]++) f=1} f {for (i in a) if (a[i]>1) printf "%sx\"%s\"-",a[i],i;print $0}' file
2x"is"-John is a teacher, who is not highly paid.
2x"abc"-abc abc abcde
2x"2"-Paul has 2 dogs and 2 cats.
```

---

Some improvement: Ignore case. Remove `.` and `,`.

```
awk '{f=0;delete a;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {w=tolower($i);sub(/[.,]/,"",w);if (a[w]++) f=1}} f' file
```